# Setup jupyter notebook in Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to setup Jupyter notebook in Google Cloud Platform but failed.

I have tried methods: (posting it for saving some time for other people)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get --assume-yes upgrade
sudo apt-get --assume-yes install software-properties-common
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-dev build-essential
sudo easy_install pip
sudo pip install jupyter ...
jupyter notebook --genrate-config
sudo nano ~/.jupyter_notebook_config.py
c=get_config()
c.NotebookApp.ip='*'
c.NotebookApp.open_browser=False
c.NotebookApp.port=8000
jupyter notebook password
jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Comment: Can you share the error it's giving to you? Where are you running these commands? (Cloud Shell or in one of the Google Cloud Platform's products?

Comment: Hi Nibrass,
I'm running commands in Cloud Shell. Kernels dead automatically. 
Shutting down 0 kernels
shivamchauhan20sep@shivam:~$ jupyter notebook --ip=0.0.0.0 --port=8156
[I 16:45:47.071 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /home/shivamchauhan20sep
[I 16:45:47.072 NotebookApp] The Jupyter Notebook is running at:
[I 16:45:47.072 NotebookApp] http://shivam:8156/
[I 16:45:47.072 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
[W 16:45:47.077 NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.

Comment: From where are you running the last command? Do you follow any documentation?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to setup jupyter notebooks on GCP ,they come pre-configured on Google AI Platform.

[GCP AI Platform notebooks](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform-notebooks)